# Laravel blade input hidden value request gives only last value , how to get uniqe id in request?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am creating laravel online examination. i have to get quetion_id ,and user selected option .Option are geting in request but in request geting only last question id .How to resolve this problem please help me...

**quiz.blade.php**

```
<div class="image-container set-full-height" style="">
    <!--   Big container   -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            @if(count($fetchQuestions) > 0)
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

                     <div class="wizard-container">

                    <div class="card wizard-card" data-color="azzure" id="wizard">
                        <div id="demo" class="text-center">

                        </div>
                        <script src="{{asset('pages/js/timer.js')}}"></script> 

                        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav"> 
                            <a class="bg-dark">{{$fetchQuestions[0]->name}}</a>
                        </div>
                        <form action="{{url('get-result')}}" method="post">
                            @csrf
                                <div class="wizard-navigation">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                                        @foreach ($fetchQuestions as $key => $question2)

                                        <li><a href="#{{$question2->id}}" data-toggle="tab">{{$question2->id}}</a></li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            <div class="tab-content" id="">

                                @foreach ($fetchQuestions as $question) 

                                <input type="hidden" id="{{$question->id}}" name="qid" value="{{$question->id}}">
                                @if($question->type != 'subjective')                      
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="{{$question->id}}">

                                   <h4 class="options">

                                    {{$question->id}}.{{$question->question}}@if($question->type == 'image_type') <img src="{{asset($question->question_image)}}">
                                    @endif

                                   </h4>
                                    <label class="radio">A. {{$question->option_a}}
                                      <input type="radio" name="user_answer" value="{{$question->option_a}}">
                                      <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="radio">B. {{$question->option_b}}
                                      <input type="radio" name="user_answer" value="{{$question->option_b}}">
                                      <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="radio">C. {{$question->option_c}}
                                      <input type="radio" name="user_answer" value="{{$question->option_c}}">
                                      <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="radio">D. {{$question->option_d}}
                                      <input type="radio" name="user_answer" value="{{$question->option_d}}">
                                      <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>  
                                @else
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="id{{$key+1}}">
                                   <h4 class="options">{{$key+1}}.{{$question->question}}</h4>
                                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answers">
                                </div>   
                                @endif    

                                @endforeach
                                <div class="wizard-footer">
                                    <div class="pull-right">
                                        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-next btn-fill btn-info btn-wd btn-sm' name='next' value='Save & Next' />
                                        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-finish btn-fill btn-info btn-wd btn-sm' name='finish' value='Finish'/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pull-left">
                                        <input type='button' class='btn btn-previous btn-fill btn-info btn-wd btn-sm' name='previous' value='Previous' />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            @else
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

                         <div class="wizard-container">

                        <div class="card wizard-card" data-color="azzure" id="wizard">
                        <div id="clockdiv" class="text-center"></div>

                        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
                            <center>Questions not found</center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endif
        </div> <!-- row -->
    </div> <!--  big container -->
</div>
```

**QuizController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\AdminControllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;
use Session;
class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function technical($student_id,$quiz_id){
    // $fetchQuestions =  DB::table('quiz_questions')->where('quiz_id','=',$quiz_id)->get();

        $fetchQuestions = DB::table('quiz_master')
        ->join('quiz_questions','quiz_questions.quiz_id','=','quiz_master.id')
        ->where('quiz_master.id','=',$quiz_id)
        ->get();



        //dd($fetchQuestions);

        return view('pages.technical',compact('fetchQuestions','student_id'));
    }
    public function getresult(Request $request){
        return $request;
        // $requestdata->session()->put('key', $request);
        dd($request->all());
        //return redirect()->back();
        //Session::put('variableName', $request->all());
    }

}
```

In controller i am returnig request data ,its giving same question_id ,how to return different question id in above code please help me..
[image]

Comment: you keep naming numerous inputs the same exact name: `qid` ... there will only be one value in the end ... the radios are all the same name for each iteration as well

Comment: Then what is the solution give me..

Comment: The name of your inputs should be an array. Where you have name="qid" should be "q_id[]".

Comment: if i am using array then its gives all id..

Comment: @lagbox said it all.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the input should be dynamic too, or else you will get only last one.

```
<input type="hidden" id="qid{{$question->id}}" name="qid{{$question->id}}" value="{{$question->id}}">
```

Now you will have all your questions.